# Sql pattern like '%A[1-9]1[012]%' (Checking values in a string value A1 to A20)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried checking pattern using `SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE QUESTION like '%A[1-9]%`  E.g A1-A9 (which is correct)

| Column A |
| --- |
| A1 |
| A2 |
| A3 |
| A4 |
| A5 |
| A6 |
| A7 |
| A8 |
| A9 |
| A10 |
| A11 |
| A12 |
| A13 |
| A14 |
| A15 |
| A16 |
| A17 |
| A18 |
| A19 |
| A20 |

Is there any solution for `'A1'`-`'A20'`?

I tried `SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE   QUESTION like '%A[1-9][2-0]%'`

Comment: I have reverted your edit. Please don't change the question in a way that invalidates existing answers. If you have a new question, please ask a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously, the correct solution would be to store the question number in a numeric column instead of hiding it inside a text column. ;-)

---

If that is not possible because you are querying an external legacy database that you cannot modify, I have an alternative suggestion:

Instead of putting it all in one *complex* pattern (which I don't think is even possible in SQL Server), just use three *simple* patterns instead. You will thank yourself for it if you ever have to modify or extend the query.

```
WHERE question LIKE 'A[1-9]'      -- 1-9
   OR question LIKE 'A1[0-9]'     -- 10-19
   OR question = 'A20'            -- 20
```

I have removed the trailing `%` because you don't want `A[1-9]` to match `A1234`, and I've removed the leading `%` because it's not necessary (according to the example data you showed in your question).

You should not need more than three conditions for numbers up to 99. For example, all questions 1-45 would be `A[1-9]`, `A[1-3][0-9]` and `A4[0-5]`.

Comment: this is the much better solution performance wise. It is the most efficient way to use an index on the column.

Comment: The OP just materially changed their example data. (Whether this new data is sufficiently representative is anyone's guess.)

Comment: @MatBailie: I have taken the liberty to revert that edit. Substantially changing the question after answers have been provided does not work well for the StackOverflow format.

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern is fixed, you can extract the number part with sub and place a condition on it

```
select * 
from dd 
where SUBSTRING( ColumnA,2,len(ColumnA)-1) between 1 and 20
```

Comment: performs very badly because it cannot use any index on `ColumnA`